# ClientCredential usage

Tags: c#, sqlmembershipprovider, wshttpbinding

I'm a beginner using WCF Service, and I'm trying to understand how the `ClientCredential` methods work. I am able to successfully use authentication using `wsHttpBinding` and `SQLMembershipProvider`.

However, I would like to know how ClientCredential does the authentication. I would like to override the login method to write some additional code around the SQLMembership one.

Moreover, I would like to know if it is possible to logoff the user from the server side.

I would also like to know how I can retrieve the MembershipUser/MembershipProvider from the server side?

Comment: Are you using a GUI WCF client?

Comment: On the server side it's a WCF Service, and a WPF Client is making the connexion with the WCF Service.

Comment: It seems that the MembershipProvider can be retrieved from the server by using MembershipProvider provider = Membership.Providers["SqlMembershipProvider"];. Closing the Authentication from the serv-side don't seem to be the problem. However, the cliencredential custom authentication is very needed here.